# ROS Tutorial issue

Tags: ros, tutorial, bagfile

I've been learning about ROS using this url ⇒(http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

And doing so I have a issue with this chapter ⇒(http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/reading%20msgs%20from%20a%20bag%20file)

It says that I have to download webviz demo from using this command

```
wget https://open-source-webviz-ui.s3.amazonaws.com/demo.bag
```

but when I did this command it gave me a error like this
--2023-11-20 14:47:17--  https://open-source-webviz-ui.s3.amazonaws.com/demo.bag
Resolving open-source-webviz-ui.s3.amazonaws.com (open-source-webviz-ui.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.214.249, 52.216.26.180, 54.231.233.185, ...
Connecting to open-source-webviz-ui.s3.amazonaws.com (open-source-webviz-ui.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.214.249|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-11-20 14:47:18 ERROR 404: Not Found.

What should I do to find?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the webviz project changed their hosting and that S3 bucket is no longer available. I would suggest reaching out to the [webviz team via a ticket](https://github.com/cruise-automation/webviz) to see if that resource is now available elsewhere and see if you can update the tutorial link to the new location.